# Send xml with russian letters RestTemplate

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, jax-rs, resttemplate

When sending xml with russian letters via rest template.
In the post method at the input I get xml with '??????'

### for example
i send xml

```
String xml = 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data id="root">
    <header>
       <XML_NAME>UPDATE</XML_NAME>
    </header>
    <body xsi:type="update" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <record id="" bid="143" number="3432ABS" surname="ПЕТРЕНКО" name="ИВАН" sname="ИВАНОВ">
       </record>
    </body>
</data>
```

### Send method

```
public <T> T sendPost(String url, String param, Object xml, Class<T> type) {
    try {
        HttpHeaders xml = new HttpHeaders();
        xml.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(entity, xml);
        ResponseEntity<T> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(String.format("%s?%s", url, param), httpEntity, type);
    
        return responseEntity;
}
```

### and in this method

```
@POST
@Path("xml")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML + "; charset=UTF-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + "; charset=UTF-8")
public Response xml(
    @QueryParam("id") BigDecimal id, String xml) throws IOException {}
```

### i get this

```
String xml = 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data id="root">
    <header>
        <XML_NAME>UPDATE</XML_NAME>
    </header>
    <body xsi:type="update" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <record id="" bid="143" number="3432ABS" surname="???????" name="????" sname="??????">
        </record>
    </body>
</data>
```

Tried various options with @Consumes. nothing helped.
But if I'm on
post endpoint I will send the same xml as postman, everything will be fine.

Comment: How are you examining the received XML?  Are you printing it in a Windows command window?

Comment: I see it in the debugger, but these values also end up in the db(Oracle)

Comment: Do you also need to set charset=UTF-8 on the RestTemplate side?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha 
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); That helped. Thanks to

Answer (score 1):

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

helped me.